# Rails 4 + Vue: Component not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, vue.js

I have a simple view:

```
<div id="purchases">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Manager</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="purchase in purchases">
        <td>{{ purchase.created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ purchase.weeks }}</td>
        <td>{{ purchase.weekly_cost }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and a simple vue component in its own js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var purchases = new Vue({
    el: '#purchases',
    data: {
      purchases: []
    },
    ready: function() {
      var that;
      that = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: '/purchases.json',
        success: function(res) {
          console.log(res)
          that.purchases = res;
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

...but no data is loading in the view and when I look at the network tab in my devtools, the ajax call is never made.  **Why would this happen?**

Comment: Are you trying to use Vue 1 or 2?

Comment: Because ready lifecycle hook is deprecated it you are using VueJS 2.0.Use `mounted`

Comment: -_-  Thanks.  That solved it.  Apparently my tutorial is outdated